# Problem with CSS transform and writing-mode properties while converting HTML to PDF dink to pdf

Tags: c#, html, css, pdf, dinktopdf

I'm trying to convert html to pdf, it works fine on browser but when I download pdf, css properties, transform and writing mode doesn't work. Here is css code example.
I am using dinktopdf c# library.

```
.left-content h2 {
        color: white;
        text-transform: uppercase;
        bottom: 65px;
        left: -25px;
        position: absolute;
        writing-mode: vertical-rl;
        transform: rotate(-90deg);
        text-orientation: mixed;
      }
```

Comment: Are you using JSPDF?

Comment: No, I'm using dinktopdf

Comment: same issue w html2pdf.js. did you find a solution?

Comment: same issue html2pdf.js., any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

Try

```css
-webkit-transform: rotate(90deg);
```

Instead of

```css
transform: rotate(-90deg);
```